# Progressive infinitive

Tags: infinitives

Could anyone please explain why I can't use "**progressive infinitive**" in the sentence below:

▪It was my fault **not to be making** you laugh.

Comment: Is it that you want to use a sentence in progressive infinitive?  Then you should go for a better example.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence reads oddly. 'Not to be making someone laugh' at a particular moment isn't exactly a fault. Perhaps you mean *It was my fault that I could not make you laugh*?